# Allowing a venv instance of Python access to I2C

Tags: i2c, python-3, permissions

I'm trying to run a python script using the adafruit_bme280 library to read a couple of sensors and display the data on a flask-generated page. I've gotten it to work outside of a venv virtual environment without using sudo, however as soon as I try to run it from within one I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site.py", line 63, in <module>
    i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
  File "/home/pav/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/busio.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.init(scl, sda, frequency)
  File "/home/pav/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/busio.py", line 27, in init
    self._i2c = _I2C(portId, mode=_I2C.MASTER, baudrate=frequency)
  File "/home/pav/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/adafruit_blinka/microcontroller/generic_l
inux/i2c.py", line 20, in __init__

    self._i2c_bus = smbus.SMBus(bus_num)
  File "/home/pav/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Adafruit_PureIO/smbus.py", line 105, in _
_init__
    self.open(bus)
  File "/home/pav/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Adafruit_PureIO/smbus.py", line 130, in o
pen
    self._device = open('/dev/i2c-{0}'.format(bus), 'r+b', buffering=0)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/i2c-1'
```

Running `i2cdetect -y 1` returns `Error: Could not open file /dev/i2c-1: Permission denied Run as root?` as expected. Running it using sudo works.

So far, I've tried adding my user name (uname) to the group i2c using `sudo adduser uname i2c`, but that hasn't had any visible effect at all. I reckon I should be able to allow my user to access i2c without using sudo but I have no idea how.

Comment: What user is the flask script running as?  You need to add whatever is actually running the script to the I2C group.

Comment: I'm running '$ python3 script.py' so I assume it's running as the user 'pi'.

Comment: I'm running '$ python3 script.py' outside of the virtual environment so I assume it's running as the user 'pi' and using it's default permissions. As far as I know 'pi' is part of the i2c group. Note that I only encounter issues when I try to run it from inside a vevn.

Answer (score 1):

***Question***

> 1. i2cdetect -y 1 returns Error, run using sudo works.
> 2. add user name to group i2c hasn't had any visible effect at all.
> 3. Allow user to access i2c without using sudo but I have no idea how.

***Answer***

> 1. sudo i2cdetect -y 1 can detect means I2C more or less OK.
> 2. Perhaps the user name has not enough permission.
> 3. Your program can do sudo things if you run it in ***desktop GUI IDLE Python***,

[image: idle python 353]